# Differential functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I'm struggling to solve this problem:
Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,+\infty[$, derivable in every point such that
$$
f'(x)=2f(2x)-f(x), \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x>0,
$$
and
$$
M_n=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^nf(x)dx<+\infty, \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall n\in\Bbb{N}.
$$
Prova that exists a non zero function that satisfies this conditions. For which sequences of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ it's true that $a_n=M_n, \ \ \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$.

All I managed to get is that
$$
M_n=n!\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2^i}{2^i-1}M_0=n!\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2^i}{2^i-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx.
$$

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Preparing for INdAM scholarship exam? ;)